# Pyspark Schema - Definition and Infer at the same time

Tags: pyspark, schema

How to define schema for some columns and infer schema for the rest? Is there a way to have partial schema definitions?

Say I have columns a, b, c; I want to define schema for just a and infer for b and c. Additionally, I'm defining schema while reading.

Comment: There is no way to have partial schema definitions . You can redefine schema what you were to infer

Comment: you could let spark infer the schema first and then cast the types for the columns you want to define yourself